# Compiler warning when sending Ether using the 'call' keyword

Tags: solidity, ether, smart-contract-wallets, eth-call

[The documentation](https://solidity-by-example.org/sending-ether/) recommends sending Ether from a smart contract using the `call` keyword:

```
function sendETH(address payable to, uint256 amount)
public
nonReentrant {
    require(address(this).balance >= amount, "Insufficient funds");
    (bool sent, bytes memory data) = to.call{value: amount}("");
    require(sent, "Failed to send Ether");
}
```

But as I'm compiling this code I'm getting a warning:

```
Warning: Unused local variable.
   --> contracts/MyContract.sol:110:21:
    |
110 |         (bool sent, bytes memory data) = to.call{value: amount}("");
    |                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Is there a way to send ether from a smart contract using the `call` keyword (as this is the latest recommended method) and avoid this warning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The compiler simply warns that this variable is not used in subsequent code. Just leave an empty space instead:

```
(bool sent,) = to.call{value: amount}("");
```